# Markdown is preventing me from adding an image from Google Charts

Tags: support, markdown, images, latex

I am stuck trying to add an image with the following code:

`![latex](https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Coint_%7B(x%2Cy)%5Cin%20C%7D%20x%5E3%5C%2C%20dx%20%2B%204y%5E2%5C%2C%20dy)`

It seems that the Stack Overflow Markdown parser is breaking my link in the middle, see:

[image: latex]

What I find pretty strange as I can add another images without any problems, see:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: Its weird that in the preview the image doesn't works but when I post the question some of them work and some not! This is what you see when you edit this post:

> [image: editing this post]

Comment: You should include a screenshot of the preview window which shows the bug!

Comment: I'll bet it's the parentheses `()` in the middle of the URL that are breaking it.

Comment: Just upload the image to the SO/SE imgur hosting? Then it's additionally safe for the future.

Comment: Actually, the other images were *not* working for me and instead the first two were missing because you forgot a closing parenthesis..

Comment: @Bart: I already added an image....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unescaped parenthesis in the URL cause the problem. Escaping them with `%28` and `%29` fixes it:

[image: latex]

`![latex](https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Coint_%7B%28x%2Cy%29%5Cin%20C%7D%20x%5E3%5C%2C%20dx%20%2B%204y%5E2%5C%2C%20dy)`

Comment: The problem was right in front of my nose and I wasn't able to see it! Thank you!